# BehaviorSubject RxJs angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I don't get the value of response in a component with BehaviorSubject. I got it and pass it in service.

I'm triggering HTTP from service on route guard.

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
projects: Subject<Project[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Project[]>([]);

load(clientId: string, active: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable<boolean>((obs) => {
        this._api.send(active ? 'projects.getActive' : 'projects.getAll',clientId).subscribe(
            res => {
                let temp = [];
                res.forEach(a => temp.push(new Project(a)));

                if (active) this.projects.next(temp);
                else this.externalProjects.next(temp);
                obs.next(true);
                obs.complete();
            },

            err => {
                obs.next(false);
                obs.complete();
            }
        );
    });
}
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // todo: check why not to load already added
    this._projectsListener = this._projectsService.projects.subscribe(a => {
        this.showIntro = a.length ? false : true;
        this.projects = a;
    });
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="project" [hidden]="!showIntro" *ngFor="let project of projects>
  {{project.title}}
</div>
```

It's just geting query param for HTTP params...
guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(
       private _projectsService: ProjectsService,
       private _router: Router) {}

   canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
       return this._projectsService.load(next.params['id'], true)
   }
}
```

I also try a `NgZone` but I'm not sure is it a right way:

```
load(clientId: string, active: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._api.send(active ? 'projects.getActive' : 'projects.getAll',clientId)
        .map(res => {
            let temp = res.map(a => new Project(a));

            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                console.log('temp: ', temp);
                if (active) this.projects.next(temp);
                else this.externalProjects.next(temp);
            });

            return true;
        })
        .catch(() => Observable.of(false));
}
```

[image]

Comment: What issue you got? You can mention, what error you getting.

Comment: Where is the `load()` called? Why do you use so many nested observables?

Comment: I'm not getting an error... just simply not rendering any data... can't get HTTP response in a component.

load() is called properly on route guard(canActivate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Don't subscribe to another observable inside an observable. Instead, write it as a stream:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
projects: Subject<Project[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Project[]>([]);

load(clientId: string, active: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._api.send(active ? 'projects.getActive' : 'projects.getAll',clientId)
        .map(res => {
                let temp = res.map(a => new Project(a));

                if (active) {
                    this.projects.next(temp);
                } else {
                    this.externalProjects.next(temp);
                }
                return true;
            })
       .catch(() => Observable.of(false));
}
```

And secondly: Don't manually subscribe to an endless stream to write the result into a class-member, use the `async`-pipe instead:

```
public projects$: Observable<Project[]> = this._projectsService.projects;
public showIntro$: Observable<boolean> = this.projects$
    .map(projects => projects.length > 0);

ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...nothing to do here
}
```

The template:

```
<div class="project" [hidden]="!showIntro" *ngFor="let project of (projects$ | async)>
  {{project.title}}
</div>
....somewhere else:
<div *ngIf="showIntro$ | async">INTRO!</div>
```

---

If your loading issue still persists, then you might want to share the contents of the `api.send` method(unless that is called for sure).

One possibility would be to have an async-method that is running outside of the ngZone, then you might want to try the following:

- Inject `NgZone` (from "@angular/core") in your service
- wrap the operations inside `this._api.send`-call inside an `ngZone.run`
- see here for more information on NgZone: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your effort, thank you. I try all the things u wrote. You're right about "observable inside an observable". I didn't provide all code of component where I unsubscribe at ngOnDestroy. The API is clean and when I `console.log(temp)` in service I got data I want but not in a component where I get an empty array. I got no errors in a console so I don't have any clue what to do, any advice will help me. I don't know is it irrelevant but I update ambitiously this app from rc6 to 4.0.0-beta.0 and everything is working well except this BehaviorSubject.

Comment: And I also try `NgZone` but not sure is it a right way... check the main post edit...

Comment: You just need to wrap the .next calls in an ngZone.run - that should already do it, no need for many layers of callbacks ect. :)

Comment: Still, doesn't work. I `console.log(projects$)` on some random click button, so I provide a screenshot.

Comment: I succeeded to get it work, but I needed to degrade bunch of packages including angular to 2.1... still didn't get it which one is breaking it without an error....